# Default captcha to magento contact us page

Tags: magento-1.7, captcha, contact-form

I am new to magento 1.7. How to add default captcha to contact us form page?

I tried online resources. But it is not useful. Is there any steps to follow, how to create module and assign to contact page. If it so, please send me webpage url, that will be helpful to me.

Can any one please help me?

Comment: pick an answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fair amount of steps and code, have a look at this tutorial: http://www.phpfunctionoftheday.com/magento-captcha-contact-form/

Overview of steps taken to incorporate native captcha into contact form page:

1. Create new module
2. Add form label + formId to adminhtml so that the form uses same settings as other pages with forms (register, login, forgotpassword, etc)
3. Reference Contact page in local.xml and define child CAPTCHA block there. Also allows you to change width/height of captcha image
4. Modify your template (.phtml) file to echo captcha child block
5. Define your module's model class location
6. Create an observer to validate captcha input

I believe that will help you a lot.

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/dchaykas/magento-captcha-contact-form)

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include at least some of the key points on the link you mention? That way, if the link goes dead you haven't wasted your time by posting a useless answer.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, I looked how magento implement captcha and I come to same steps described here. ( at least on magento 1.9.x )

Answer (score -2):

This is the link that you are looking for.. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/298363/ .. Remove the "\\" in the post and add the code as suggested here.. I use this..

Answer (score -3):

There is a free extension which integrates Magento's native captcha on Contact Us form.

You can find it here: [Easy Contact Form Captcha](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-contact-form-captcha.html)

Also its FREE.